# Subadditivity of Probability Measure and Independence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space, and $A_i\in\mathcal F$ for $i=1,2,\dots, n$. Suppose that $A_i\cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$, and $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^\complement\right) = \prod_{i=1}^nP(A_i^\complement)$, i.e., the complementary events are independent.

Then $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right) = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i)}_{=:a}$$ by additivity of probability measures, and $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\right) = 1 - P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^\complement\right) = \underbrace{1-\prod_{i=1}^nP(A_i^\complement)}_{=: b}.$$

For simplicity, assume that $P(A_i) = c$ for all $i = 1,2,\dots, n$. Then $a = nc$ and $b = 1 - (1-c)^n$. The Binomial Theorem yields $$b = 1-\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}n \\ k\end{pmatrix}(-c)^k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n\begin{pmatrix}n \\ k\end{pmatrix}(-c)^k.$$

Let's take $n = 2$. Then $a = 2c$ and $b = 2c+c^2$, so $a\neq b$.

Where is my mistake? I am sitting on this problem for 1 hour now and can't spot my error.

Comment: Why do you think $a=2c$?  Why do you think the binomial theorem holds here?  Recall that $\Pr(X\cup Y)\neq \Pr(X)+\Pr(Y)$ except in special circumstances, specifically when $X$ and $Y$ are **mutually exclusive** (*or at least have trivial intersection*).  Recall that $\Pr(X\cap Y)\neq \Pr(X)\times \Pr(Y)$ except in special circumstances, specifically when $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**.  Being mutually exclusive is not the same thing as being independent.  Those mean totally different things in mathematics.

Comment: You can not have simultaneously that your events are mutually exclusive and independent (*which would have followed from the complements being independent*).  Those are contradictory statements.  The only way that could happen is if the events all had their probability equal to zero

Comment: Note... you could have come to this conclusion as well, since if $2c=2c+c^2$ that implies that $0=c^2$ and thus $0=c$

Comment: I see, so my setting is not well-defined. I can have mutually exclsive but then the independence of compelementary events does not hold (or vice versa). Thank you!